# Loading shapefile with altair, getting only gibberish

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, geopandas, altair

I'm trying to create a cloropleth map using Italian provinces. I downloaded the shapefiles from [here](https://www.istat.it/storage/cartografia/confini_amministrativi/generalizzati/Limiti01012022_g.zip), when I load the .shp file into [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) everything works, but when I try to load the file using altair on my computer I obtain a nonsensical plot. What AM I doing wrong? I followed some tutorials and I should be doing everything right. I'm reading the .shp file using geopandas.

[image: altarir code]

Comment: How does the output of `gdf.plot` or `gdf.explore` look like? We need to understand if the issue comes from geopandas od Altair.

Answer (score 2):

This is all down to the CRS of the data.  Projecting *GeoDataFrame* to epsg:4286 first resolves the issue. (This code requires download code to be run before plotting code)

#### plot

```
import altair as alt
gdf = gdfs["ProvCM01012022_g_WGS84.shp"].to_crs("epsg:4286")

alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='black'
)
```

#### output

[image]

#### download data

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tempfile
import requests, urllib
import geopandas as gpd
url = "https://www.istat.it/storage/cartografia/confini_amministrativi/generalizzati/Limiti01012022_g.zip"

f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    f = Path(d).joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(d)
    gdfs = {f.name:gpd.read_file(f) for f in Path(d).rglob("*.shp")}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this interesting recipe. Side remark: Instead of 

f = Path(d).joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])

you could use

f = Path(d)/Path(url).name

Comment: @cast42 it could be a constant `Path(d).joinpath("download.zip")` as a temp dir is being used.  copy paste from another recipe ;-).  i.e. no need to use **urllib** at all